# Google map image in other Location is unclear

Tags: java, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-3

I'm new to android.
I've searched for while, but I couldn't find answer for my question.

I made an application displaying images.

map on my current location is quite clear.

but map imapge on other location is really unclear.

Is there anyone can help me?

Kindly find attached my captured image as below,

[image]

and my code is as below,

```js
package org.androidtown.burningfriday;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    GoogleMap mMap;
    private static final int ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;

    private GoogleApiClient mLocationClient;
    private LocationListener mListenter;
    private Marker marker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (servicesOK()) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
            if (initMap()) {

                gotoLocation(37, 128, 5);
                mLocationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                        .build();
                mLocationClient.connect();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "맵핑서비스에 연결못함", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    }

    public boolean servicesOK() {
        int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return true;
        } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError((isAvailable))) {
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this, ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "맵핑서비스에 연결못함", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return false;

    }

    private boolean initMap() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mMap = mapFragment.getMap();
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

            if (mMap != null) {
                mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);
                        TextView tvLocality = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvLocality);
                        TextView tvLat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvLat);
                        TextView tvLng = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvLng);
                        TextView tvSnippet = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvSnippet);

                        LatLng latLng = marker.getPosition();
                        tvLocality.setText(marker.getTitle());
                        tvLat.setText("Latitude:" + latLng.latitude);
                        tvLng.setText("Longitude:" + latLng.longitude);
                        tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

                        return v;
                    }
                });
                mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                        String msg = marker.getTitle() + "("+marker.getPosition().latitude+","+marker.getPosition().longitude+")";
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        return false;
                    }

                });

            }

        }
        return (mMap != null);
    }

    private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng, float zoom) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom);
        mMap.moveCamera(update);
    }

    private void hideSoftKeyboard(View v) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    public void geoLocate(View v) throws IOException {
        hideSoftKeyboard(v);


        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String searchString = tv.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Searching for : " + searchString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
        List<android.location.Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(searchString, 1);
        if (list.size() > 0) {
            android.location.Address add = list.get(0);
            String locality = add.getLocality();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Found : " + locality, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            double lat = add.getLatitude();
            double lng = add.getLongitude();
            gotoLocation(lat, lng, 10);

            if (marker != null) {
                marker.remove();
            }


            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(add.getLocality())
                    .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_backward));

            String country = add.getCountryName();
            if (country.length() > 0) {
                options.snippet(country);
            }
            marker = mMap.addMarker(options);
        }
    }




    public void showCurrentLocation(View v) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .getLastLocation(mLocationClient);
        if (currentLocation == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "위치 설정을 켜주시기 바랍니다.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15);
            mMap.animateCamera(update);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mLocationClient,mListenter
        );
    }
}
```

Thankyou

Comment: Is it only become blurry when zooming in?

Comment: When I zoom in current location, map is not blurry,

But when I zoom in other location, it become blurry.
For example, 
when I put in specific location and search,
applicattion moves to right locaion on map, but it become blurry if I zoom in.

Comment: yes, But don't you get clear screen after some time?

Comment: No...I waited some time, but I didn't get clear screen. It dosen't have any problem on code?

Comment: Sorry guys!
It is working well today. I missd something yesterday maybe...Kindly understand about my mistake. Thank you!!

Comment: can u post the error that you found out? and what steps did you do to solve it. So other people here can solve the same problem if its happen to them.